# How to get document height and width without using jquery

Tags: javascript

How to get document height and width in pure [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) i.e without using [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery).
I know about `$(document).height()` and `$(document).width()`, but I want to do this in [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript).

I meant page's height and width.

Comment: http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/get-document-height-cross-browser/

Answer (score 149):

```
var height = document.body.clientHeight;
var width = document.body.clientWidth;
```

Check:  [this article](http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/javascript/browserwindow) for better explanation.

Comment: This is not cross browser. You should have tested this before posting it.

Comment: @Iwazaru Thanks for pointing that out. Looks like this 4 years old reply isn't bulletproof :)

Comment: It seems [it is cross-browser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/clientHeight#Browser_compatibility).

Comment: If a website has a border it takes that off the width with this solution but not the jQuery solution. Unlikely to be a border on the body but worth knowing. `window.innerWidth` solves this

Comment: This returns the height of the browser window (if you adjust the height of the browser it changes), not the height of the content/webpage.

Answer (score 63):

Even the last example given on http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/javascript/browserwindow is not working on Quirks mode. Easier to find than I thought, this seems to be the solution(extracted from latest jquery code):

```
Math.max(
    document.documentElement["clientWidth"],
    document.body["scrollWidth"],
    document.documentElement["scrollWidth"],
    document.body["offsetWidth"],
    document.documentElement["offsetWidth"]
);
```

just replace Width for "Height" to get Height.

Comment: This should be the correct answer. clientWidth does not always have the right value.

Comment: problem with clientWidth is it is viewable only. scrollWidth includes things leaking off the screen. at least, this is true for my Chrome experiments in 2019.

Comment: @StayCool it seems that the most recent jQuery is still using this method for the document height/width calculation and it gives the same result as `$(document).width()`. Maybe you are after something like `$(window).width()` which in pure JS would be just `document.documentElement["clientWidth"]` on modern browsers.

Answer (score 44):

This is a cross-browser solution:

```
var w = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.body.clientWidth;
var h = window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight || document.body.clientHeight;
```

Comment: This is a safe and accurate thing to do

Comment: this is returning the window height and width, not the document height and width

Answer (score 26):

You should use `getBoundingClientRect` as it usually **works cross browser** and gives you **sub-pixel precision** on the bounds rectangle.

```
elem.getBoundingClientRect()
```

Comment: for those wondering about support: http://caniuse.com/#feat=getboundingclientrect

Comment: this returns a height of 0 when i used it on document.body

Comment: Probably because your body has height 0. If you don't change its display type that's the case by default. Check it in the DOM inspector.

Answer (score 14):

Get document size without jQuery

```
document.documentElement.clientWidth
document.documentElement.clientHeight
```

And use this if you need Screen size

```
screen.width
screen.height
```

Answer (score 8):

You can try also:

```
document.body.offsetHeight
document.body.offsetWidth
```

Comment: Be careful of using these in things like window resize events. they have to calculate the height & width, which takes a while.

Answer (score 8):

This should work for all browsers/devices:

```
function getActualWidth()
{
    var actualWidth = window.innerWidth ||
                      document.documentElement.clientWidth ||
                      document.body.clientWidth ||
                      document.body.offsetWidth;

    return actualWidth;
}
```

Comment: window.innerWidth is the only one that is also correct when the dev tools are open on Chrome

Answer (score 4):

If you want to get the full width of the page, including overflow, use [`document.body.scrollWidth`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_element_scrollwidth.asp).

Comment: Is this solution cross browser?

Answer (score 2):

`window` is the whole browser's application window. `document` is the webpage shown that is actually loaded.

`window.innerWidth` and `window.innerHeight` will take scrollbars into account which may not be what you want.

`document.documentElement` is the full webpage without the top scrollbar. `document.documentElement.clientWidth` returns document width size without y scrollbar.
`document.documentElement.clientHeight` returns document height size without x scrollbar.

Answer (score 1):

How to find out the document width and height very easily?

in HTML
`<span id="hidden_placer"   style="position:absolute;right:0;bottom:0;visibility:hidden;"></span>`

in javascript

```
     var c=document.querySelector('#hidden_placer');

     var r=c.getBoundingClientRect();
     r.right=document width
     r.bottom=document height`
```

You may update this on every window resize event, if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

`var w = window.innerWidth;`

`var h = window.innerHeight;`

It gets the browser window width and height.
This has more info:
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_get_current_window.asp

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>Get the size of the current screen/window</h2>
<p>The example displays the browser window's height and width: (NOT including toolbars/scrollbars)

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var w = window.innerWidth;
var h = window.innerHeight;

var x = document.getElementById("demo");
x.innerHTML = "Code snippet width: " + w + ", height: " + h + ".";
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Try it here:
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_get_current_window