# Getting the document's width and height

Tags: javascript

I'm curious how I would get the width of the document, it looks like I can get the width of the window using `document.body.offsetWidth` but everything else I try is like a few pixels different from `document.body.offsetWidth` and I need the document's width which is larger, and doesn't change when the window is resized.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function getSize()
{
    var w=window,d=document,e=d.documentElement,g=d.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
    var x=w.innerWidth||e.clientWidth||g.clientWidth;
    var y=w.innerHeight||e.clientHeight||g.clientHeight;
    return {width:x, height:y}
}
var size=getSize();
console.log(size.width+" "+size.height);
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/7vy3J/1/)

Comment: this returns the size of the window, that is why the values change when I change the size of the result frame, I need the value that does no change when there is an image taking up 2000x3000 pixels (for example).

Comment: http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/javascript/browserwindow and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5484578/how-to-get-document-height-and-width-without-using-jquery

Comment: +1 for vanilla JavaScript, whether the OP asked for it or jQuery; we often forget how easy libraries like jQuery make JavaScript.