# How to get document's height?

Tags: javascript, dom, height

I am trying to get document's height, so I can do comparisons about in which part of the document a particular  element is.

Here is what I have found [How to get documet height and width without using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5484578/how-to-get-document-height-and-width-without-using-jquery). However, when I open that particular link, and I open the Chrome Inspect Console and type:

```
document.body.clientHeight
```

I get

**2405**

This is weird because if I sum up the heights of the different parts of the site (header, content, footer), it doesn't count 2405. Particularly I get:

header: 120px 
content: 450px 
footer: 439px

What am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: What do the parts sum up to?

Comment: depends, does the content not reach the bottom of the page, or does it extend beyond the page?

Comment: @SuperScript I have edited my question with the sum up I get.

Comment: @zzzzBov It is extended beyond the page. But I am trying to get the original height of the document, no matter if you are looking it with a bigger/smaller screen. I want to know what is the height of the document, so later I can figure out if a particular image is in the "upper" part or the "lower" part of the document.

Comment: I think you should make a [reduced test case on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) so that we can see the HTML that you're using that would cause this issue. I can only guess that you missed some elements, got the height incorrectly, or forgot to include margins/paddings in accessing the heights.

Comment: zzzzBov I'm using the HTML of this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5484578/how-to-get-document-height-and-width-without-using-jquery