# Determining the browser width with standalone code

Tags: javascript

I got this code from this question ([How to get document height and width without using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5484578/how-to-get-document-height-and-width-without-using-jquery)) :

```
width = Math.max(
    document.documentElement.clientWidth,
    document.body.scrollWidth,
    document.documentElement.scrollWidth,
    document.body.offsetWidth,
    document.documentElement.offsetWidth
);
```

How reliable is it? It doesn't seem to work as expected on Opera 12 - but that's rather old now.

Other than that browser it seems to be OK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`document.documentElement.clientWidth` and `window.innerWidth` should work across all browsers (you can test here https://ryanve.com/lab/dimensions/). Opera 12 is 8 years old and not available for testing on https://browserstack.com so I wasn’t able to test.

FYI, if you care about the scrollbar width, check out these posts:

- [How to get screen width without (minus) scrollbar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8339377/how-to-get-screen-width-without-minus-scrollbar)
- [Get the height and width of the browser viewport without scrollbars using jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8794338/get-the-height-and-width-of-the-browser-viewport-without-scrollbars-using-jquery/35008384)