# How to get full page height with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, puppeteer

Is there any way of getting the full page height including scrollable content?

For example, in the page below I have a height of 613px, but with a lot more content that was scrolled out. If a get the value of `document.documentElement.scrollHeight` it gives me the same 613px. Is there any way I can actually get the full page height?

[image]

### EDIT:

I've tried some of the answers, but somehow, for this page I always get the same height (https://material.angular.io/). Does someone know why?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3044355/3953479, it should help

Comment: "The Element.scrollHeight read-only property is a measurement of the height of an element's content, **including content not visible on the screen due to overflow.**" this should include your off screen content as well.

Comment: I think its `document.body.clientHeight`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get document height and width without using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5484578/how-to-get-document-height-and-width-without-using-jquery)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will give you a height of scrollable area too

```
(function() {
    let pageHeight = 0;

    function findHighestNode(nodesList) {
        for (let i = nodesList.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (nodesList[i].scrollHeight && nodesList[i].clientHeight) {
                var elHeight = Math.max(nodesList[i].scrollHeight, nodesList[i].clientHeight);
                pageHeight = Math.max(elHeight, pageHeight);
            }
            if (nodesList[i].childNodes.length) findHighestNode(nodesList[i].childNodes);
        }
    }

    findHighestNode(document.documentElement.childNodes);

    console.log('You page hight it', pageHeight);
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
window.outerHeight
```

I think this will help you to get window height with scrollable area.

Comment: `outerHeight` it includes the page and all the visible browser's bars (location, status, bookmarks, window title, borders, …).

Comment: Try this one. Find the id of the scrollable area or add one id in the body and try this document.getElementById("bo_dy").scrollHeight

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @reachtokish, `document.querySelector('body').scrollHeight` will give you the whole height of the scrollable page

Answer (score 0):

With the developer tools console you can try it for this page

```js
var pageHeight = document.documentElement.scrollHeight;
```

This looks like this

[image: console pageheight]